# Best way to process data in a Rails service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a reminder service which takes some 'changes requests' and then sends them to a worker queue to perform at a later date.
Each 'change request' can either have a 'ten minute before' reminder and or a 'one hour after reminder'. It will also have different types of reminders in the future.

I'm looking for the most polished ruby kind way of processing and sending each of the reminders to the worker lots of if statements doesn't feel right but I may be wrong!

```
class ReminderService

  # @data
  # ten_minute_before: data[:ten_minutes_before_reminder] bool,
  # one_hour_after: data[:one_hour_after_reminder] bool,
  # user: user,
  # price_change_ids: data[:change_requests],
  # user_hash: user_hash(user)

  attr_accessor :data, :user

  def initialize(user, data)
    {data[:price_change_ids]}
    @user = user
    @data = data
  end

  def run
    change_requests
  end

  def send
    reminderWorker.perform_at(action_reminder_at, price_change_id, reminder_type, user, user_hash)
  end

  def change_requests
    data[:price_change_ids]
  end

  def user_hash
    data[:user_hash]
  end

  def action_reminder_at
    DateTime.parse(price_change_at) - 11.minutes
  end

  def price_change_id
    data[:price_change_ids].first.id
  end

  def price_change_at
    data[:user_hash][:price_change_at_time]
  end
end
```

Worker service:

```
class PriceReminderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options queue: 'price_reminders', retry: true

  def perform(price_change_id, reminder, user, data)
    id = price_change_id
    price_change = priceChangeRequest.find(id)

    if reminder[:ten_minutes_before]
      reminderMailer.notify(user, data).deliver_later unless price_change.cancelled_at
    end

    if reminder[:one_hour_after]
      Sms::priceChangeSms.new(build_hash(user)).submit unless price_change.cancelled_at
    end
  end

  def build_hash(user)
    {
        to: Phonelib.parse(user.mobile_number).full_e164,
        company_id: user&.company&.id,
        user_name: user.first_name,
        admin_user_name: data[:from_admin_user],
        body: Sms::Message::priceChangeMessage.new(data).build
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to stick with your current `PriceChangeRequest` structure, then I think I would do:

```
class PriceReminderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'price_reminders', retry: true

  attr_accessor *%w( price_change_id user data ).freeze

  def perform(price_change_id, reminder, user, data)
    @price_change_id  = price_change_id
    @user             = user
    @data             = data 

    %i(
      ten_minutes_before
      one_hour_after
    ).each do |time_sym|
      send("send_#{time_sym}_reminder") if price_change_request.send("#{time_sym}_reminder")
    end if price_change_request

  end

private 

  def user_hash
    {
      to:               Phonelib.parse(user.mobile_number).full_e164,
      company_id:       user&.company&.id,
      user_name:        user.first_name,
      admin_user_name:  data[:from_admin_user],
      body:             Sms::Message::priceChangeMessage.new(data).build
    }
  end

  def send_ten_minutes_before_reminder
    reminderMailer.notify(user, data).deliver_later unless price_change.cancelled_at
  end

  def send_one_hour_after_reminder
    Sms::priceChangeSms.new(user_hash).submit unless price_change.cancelled_at
  end

  def price_change_request
    @price_change_request ||= PriceChangeRequest.find(price_change_id)
  end

end
```

But, I think it's not a great idea to have a bunch of `booleans` like `ten_minutes_before_reminder` and `one_hour_after_reminder` on your `PriceChangeRequest` class. Especially if you start to have many reminder types. You'll likely end up with sparsely populated boolean fields which isn't that great. And, you'll have to run new migrations every time you want to add a new reminder type. Blah, blah, blah.

If I were you, I think I would be tempted to have a `ReminderTime` class something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: reminder_times
#
#  id           :bigint           not null, primary key
#  system_name  :string           not null
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#
class ReminderTime < ApplicationRecord
  validates :system_name, presence: true
  has_many :price_change_request_reminder_times
  has_many :price_change_requests, through: :price_change_request_reminder_times
end
```

And a `PriceChangeRequestReminderTime` something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: price_change_request_reminder_times
#
#  id                       :bigint           not null, primary key
#  reminder_time_id         :integer          not null
#  price_change_request_id  :integer          not null
#  created_at               :datetime         not null
#  updated_at               :datetime         not null
#
class PriceChangeRequestReminderTime < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reminder_time
  belongs_to :price_change_request
end
```

Then, in your `PriceChangeRequest`, do something like:

```
class PriceChangeRequest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :price_change_request_reminder_times
  has_many :reminder_times, through: :price_change_request_reminder_times

  def set_reminder_times(*time_syms)
    time_syms.each do |time_sym|
      reminder_times << ReminderTime.find_or_create_by!(system_name: time_sym)
    end
  end

  def remove_reminder_times(*type_syms)
    price_change_request_reminder_times.
      where(reminder_time: ReminderTime.find_by(system_name: type_syms)).
      destroy_all
  end

  def reminder_time_names
    reminder_times.pluck(:system_name)
  end

end
```

To set reminder times, you would do something like:

```
@price_change_request.set_reminder_times :ten_minutes_before
```

Or

```
@price_change_request.set_reminder_times :ten_minutes_before, :one_hour_after
```

To remove reminder times, you would do something like:

```
@price_change_request.remove_reminder_times :ten_minutes_before
```

Or

```
@price_change_request.remove_reminder_times :one_hour_after, :ten_minutes_before
```

...so that you could do something like:

```
class PriceReminderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'price_reminders', retry: true

  attr_accessor *%w( 
    price_change_id 
    user 
    data 
  ).freeze

  delegate *%w(
    reminder_time_names
  ), to: :price_change_request

  def perform(price_change_id, reminder, user, data)
    @price_change_id  = price_change_id
    @user             = user
    @data             = data 
    reminder_time_names.each do |reminder_time_name|
      send("send_#{reminder_time_name}_reminder")
    end if price_change_request
  end

private 

  def user_hash
    {
      to:               Phonelib.parse(user.mobile_number).full_e164,
      company_id:       user&.company&.id,
      user_name:        user.first_name,
      admin_user_name:  data[:from_admin_user],
      body:             Sms::Message::priceChangeMessage.new(data).build
    }
  end

  def send_ten_minutes_before_reminder
    reminderMailer.notify(user, data).deliver_later unless price_change.cancelled_at
  end

  def send_one_hour_after_reminder
    Sms::priceChangeSms.new(user_hash).submit unless price_change.cancelled_at
  end

  def price_change_request
    @price_change_request ||= PriceChangeRequest.find(price_change_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Hey, I can see what you're doing and it makes sense. Just to clarify, each change request can have either a 'ten minute reminder' and or a 'one hour reminder'

Comment: Are you saying that `ten_minute_reminder` and `one_hour_reminder` are somehow derived from the `@price_change`? If so, how does a `priceChangeRequest` "have" these reminders? BTW, `priceChangeRequest` is a unconventional class name. As is `priceReminderWorker`. The conventional forms would be `PriceChangeRequest` and `PriceReminderWorker`.

Comment: Yes exactly, so this is what a price change looks like: 
```#<PriceChangeRequest id: 45, user_id: 456, *********, ten_minutes_before_reminder: true, one_hour_after_reminder: false>,```

Comment: Also, is the `user` that you're passing in associated with the `PriceChangeRequest`? If so, how? And what about `data`? Where does that come from?